# Laravel date of birth validation

Tags: laravel-8

In my form when date of birth is entered  it will come to Validator of laravel.
The required and greater than 18 years are working correctly. But less than 65 years not working.

my code is

```
('dob' => required |date|after:18 years|before:65 years,)

$messages = ('dob.required' => 'Date of Birth Required',
             'dob.before' => 'Age should be less than 65 years',
             'dob.after' => 'Age should be above 18',)
```

Comment: You've got a comma after "65 years" that could be throwing it.

Comment: After that statement there is email validation etc. So is the coma. That is not throwing this error

Answer (score 0):

```
'dob' => 'required |date|after:18 years|before:65 years|nullable'
```